# Installed Office 365 offline. How do I start it?

Tags: windows-7, office365

Using Office 365 in Chrome works, but mailto-links don't, and for other reasons as well I'd prefer a dedicated mail app.

The installer did its thing and I restarted. The guides tell me to use the Office 2013 application icons, but when I start Outlook 2013 it wants me to set up my account ("Do you want to set up Outlook to connect to an email account?").

How do I set up my Office 365 account on Outlook 2013 on Windows 7? I have tried to enter my name, email, and the password that I use for Office 365, but on the next screen it never finishes the step "searching for  settings", so it never gets to the step "Logging on to the mail server".

PS. I don't think it's related, but my IE crashes all the #%¤ time, so I don't use that at all. This is a new (to me) laptop, for a new job position, so I can't say what the software history of the machine is beyond two days ago. :(

Comment: [Solved] but I cannot mark it as such until two days have passed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, how am I supposed to close this question if you delete my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind ... it just took over 15 minutes to complete. Not what I expected. (@MartijnPieters, how am I supposed to close this question if you delete my answer?)